# Deserialize object into own type in C#

Tags: c#, object, xamarin, type-conversion, deserialization

I am new to c# and I am willing to convert a Object into a class representing a User. I am retrieving the object from a http request to an API. My code is:

```
 private async void getUser()
        {
            var requestURI = new HttpRequestMessage();
            string url = "https:...";
            requestURI.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
            requestURI.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            requestURI.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage responseURI = await client.SendAsync(requestURI);
            if (responseURI.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Get User OK");
                var UserString = await responseURI.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("User: " + UserString);
                var UsersJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(UsersString);
                Debug.WriteLine(UserJson);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("User GET request failed");
            }
        }
```

The output is:

```
{
  "Username": "Alice",
  "IP": "192.13.2.2",
  "Levels": "1,2"
}
```

How do I create a class or a type to later deserealize this object into it? When the type/class is created, how do I deserealize the object into it?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Please check this out for future reference on how to do Serializing and Deserializing of JSON

                         

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use this website - https://json2csharp.com/ - to generate the C# classes.

In this case, the class would be as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string Levels { get; set; }
}
```

For deserialization to this class, you can use as follows:

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(UsersString);
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I access to each field of a User? User.getUsername()?

Comment: string username = user.Username;

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if i can call getUser() function multiple times from a for and un every iteration créate a new User? Thanks

Comment: You can do that. But it's an async function. To avoid locking, please await the call.

Eg. await getUser();

Comment: Yes, i got that. However, how do i create two different users in each iteration?

Comment: This is like a c# class! :) Initialize each object and add to a list. eg. 

List<User> listofUsers = new List<User>();

In your for loop, you can use the following - 

User tempUser = new User();
tempUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

listofUsers.Add(tempUser);

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string Levels { get; set; }
}
```

The you Deserialize an Object like this: Please have a look at this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```